# Cassandra time series data (right approach?)

Tags: java, cassandra

We have a table that will contain a huge amount of time series data. Probably we have to store several entries per millisecond in that table. To fulfill these requirements the table looks like

```sql
CREATE TABLE statistic (
    name        text,
    id          uuid,
    start       timestamp,
    other_data  ...,

PRIMARY KEY (name, start, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (start DESC);
```

As you can see, the table consists of two clustering keys, `start` stores the time when the data arrives, `id` has the purpose to avoid that data is overwritten when it arrives at the same time.

Now this is ok, we can make range queries like

```sql
SELECT * FROM statistic WHERE name ='foo' AND start >= 1453730078182
     AND start <= 1453730078251;
```

But we also need the capability to have additional search parameters in the query like

```sql
SELECT * FROM statistic WHERE name = 'foo' 
    AND start >= 1453730078182 AND start <= 1453730078251 AND other_data = 'bar';
```

This does not work of course because `other_data` is not part of the primary key. If we add it to the primary key, we get the following error

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY column "other_data" cannot be restricted (preceding column "start" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)"

That is also OK, that is not the way `Cassandra` works (I think).

Our approach to solve the problem is to select the needed (time series) data with the above mentioned (first) range query and afterwards filter the data in our Java application. That means we go through the list and kick out all data we don't need in our Java application. One single entry has not much data, but it can happen that we talk about some millions of rows in worst case.

Now I have two questions:

1. Is that the right approach to solve the problem?
2. Is Cassandra capable to handle that amount of data?

Comment: Have you seen this talk on YouTube about how they implemented a time series database with Cassandra? [UBS Securities: A Journey with Cassandra at UBS Securities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIAO2Ad6ln8). It might contain some good ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll watch that video as far as I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This does not work of course because other_data is not part of the primary key. If we add it to the primary key, we get the following error

This is a sweet spot for secondary index on column **other_data**. In your case this index will scale because you always provide the partition key (*name*) so Cassandra will not hit all nodes in the cluster.

With a secondary index on **other_data**, your second SELECT statement will be possible.

Now there is another issue with your data model, which is the partition size. Indeed, if you are inserting **several entries per milliseconds per name**, this will not scale because the partition for each name will grow very fast ...

If the insert is distributed on different partition keys (different *name*) then it's fine

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This sounds like a good idea I totally forgot. The cardinality of the columns that will get a `secondary index` will be around 250 different values. The inserts is distributed as the name column has a high cardinality. The total amount of columns will also be not to high (around 20). Do you see any problems there? And is the amount of secondary indices important? I think we will need about max. 10.

Comment: In your case, if you have a huge amount of  `name` it's perfect. Cassandra will distribute it all over the cluster and secondary index restriction by partition key will work like a charm. "And is the amount of secondary indices important?"  --> The more you have secondary indices, the more you consume your write throughput, there is no magic. For read performance, as long as you provide partition key, it should be fine